# HTML button not displaying on success of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to display an input button on the success message in my view. I am working in MVC 3 application using razor views. This button will allow the user to navigate to another view.

#### Controller.

```
var successfull = new string[]
{
  "All " + builder.Data.Count.ToString() + " work items were added successfully."
};

return new JsonResult
{
   Data = new { success = true, msg = successfull}
};
```

#### JavaScript.

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(json);

$.ajax({
   url: '/Builder/CreateWork',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: jsonText,
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (result) {
     // clear table
     $('#instruments-data').empty();
     resultMessage(result);
   },
   complete: function () {
     // hides the loading gif
     $('.loading').hide();
   }
});
```

#### View

```
<div id="resultMessage"></div>
```

Is there a way to add to the ajax code to include the following input button.

```
<input type="button" class="styledbutton" value="Some text" onclick="window.location.href='Url.Action("action", "controller")';" />
```

#### EDIT ---

The problem lies with this piece of code - but can't see the problem.

```
        onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")'"/>');
```

Please advise.

Comment: Of course,  it is `ajax` after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the previous answers were allowing for re-direct, so I found a work around.

```
  success: function (result) {
                // clear table
                $('#instruments-data').empty();
                resultMessage(result);
                $('#resultMessage').append('<input type="button" id="MultiStatus"class="styledbutton" value="Button text" />');
                $('#MultiStatus').click(function (e) {
                    location.href = "/Controller/Action";
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate html in ajax call as given below :

```
<div id="div1"><div>

success: function (result) {
                // clear table
                $('#instruments-data').empty();
                resultMessage(result);
                $('#div1').html('<input type="button" class="styledbutton" value="Some text" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")'/>')
            }
```

Above Code will work fine,just generate html in ajax call as above.

Comment: I included the above and closed quotes where needed...$('#div1').html('<input type="button" class="styledbutton" value="Some text" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")'"/>'); .... it doesn't hit the alert I put in front of it and I have green lines under @Url - conditional complication is turned off and under '"/>' - expected , or )   any ideas ?

Comment: no, it skips the success function altogether.no mgs displays, the data doesn't save to the db either

Answer (score 0):

The button is static so you can hide it

```
<input style="display:none" type="button" class="styledbutton" value="Some text" onclick="window.location.href='Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';" />
```

And then in success callback show it

```
            success: function (result) {
            // clear table
            $('#instruments-data').empty();
            resultMessage(result);
            //show button
            $(".styledbutton").show();
        },
```

Comment: Tired the above ...<input style="display:none" type="button" id="statusbtn" class="styledbutton" value="Some text" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';"/> and even put an alert in front, the alert was reached, but button did not display ? Had to use Id as there are other btnd with the same class in view

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple way. As you have been advised, you can hide the button initially using `css`.

```
<input type="button" class="styledbutton" style="display:none;" value="demo" onclick="window.location.href='Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';"/>
```

you just need little bit tweak in your `js` code if everything behind the scenes is working fine (i mean model and controllers).

use `done()` instead of `success` and likewise `always()` instead of `complete` if you are using `jQuery v 1.8` or higher. Check the deprecation notice in [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). `success` and `complete` are no longer in use as of `jQuery 1.8+`

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/Builder/CreateWork',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: jsonText,
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
 }).done(function(result){
     // clear table
     $('#instruments-data').empty();
     resultMessage(result);
     //just show the button
     $(".styledbutton").show();
 }).always(function(){
     // hides the loading gif
     $('.loading').hide();
});
```

**Note:** Place your button exactly where you want to see it on view and make it `display:none`. Ajax will handle the rest. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: The good news is, it saved the data to the Db as it should - bad news no button was displayed, there must be a problem with this syntax in the simple way - onclick="window.location.href='Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")';", as the input does display without it...also please not I had to use id="demo" and $('#demo'), as I have other btn's with the same class.

Comment: Name of `ID` does not matter, it is up to you whatever you choose. I just gave for demonstration. Beisdes try showing the button by accessing `ID`, although it will not make any difference. Did you put the input button on page by making it `display:none`??

Answer (score 0):

If you want advice, i would suggest you to try anchor button with bootstrap styling to reflect the feel of a button.

can you please try this if that doesn't hurt your intention.

example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ButtonText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new { @id = "Query", @class = "btn btn-inverse styledButton" })
```

i have included a jsbin demo about how to use the button for your specific need, please follow this link: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/wemuxayo/1/edit)

Feel free to comment if you need any explanation